# I have 3 copies of the same file, each corrupted at a different point. Is there a way to restore the original file?

Tags: file-corruption

Title mostly says it all. Is there a program or something that you can put your files into that would spit out the original?

imagine file copy 1: 001

imagine file copy 2: 010

imagine file copy 3: 100

you can deduce each original bit by reading down the line and finding the most common right?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Asking for a program is off-topic. If you can program you could open each file as binary and compare it yourself, spitting out a file that has at least 2 bits the same in the output file. If however the files are not entirely the same, this will not work. For example, an image that is compressed differently but is otherwise the same image can appear the same, but will have a different file. In that case this will be impossible.

Comment: How low level are we talking about? Going to the byte level and assuming that all files are of the same size, you could iterate over all three, find the most common byte and write it to a new file. If you know the ranges of the corrupted file, you could stitch them together with the command dd.

Comment: LPChip - where do I go to learn how to do that?

Adam - how would I do that? (or where would I go to learn?)

Comment: first step: Are the files exactly the same size?  i.e: Place them together in any folder and do `ls -l file1 file2 file3` - add the output to your question. Oh BTW; as you haven't told - I assume we have a Linux OS as tool.

Comment: Hannu - The files are exactly the same size they are identical copies of 1 original file that have had bits flipped in them, all at different locations, as to render the files corrupted or otherwise unusable. I'm running windows but could always use linux as a tool.

Comment: Are you able to share the files?

Comment: This is probably off topic here, but assuming the files are identically sized you should be able to write a fairly simple program in any language that can handle disk io.

Comment: davidgo: please direct me to a place where I could begin to learn what kind of script/program I would need to write. HelpingHand: i can't; assume the files are the 3 files in the original question, but much longer (too long to do manually)